# Remote connectivity issue

Tags: c#, powershell, remote-access, powershell-remoting

**Below is how I am trying to connect**

```
string shellUri = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell";
string password = "*****";
System.Security.SecureString securePW = new System.Security.SecureString();
foreach (char c in password)
     securePW.AppendChar(c);
securePW.MakeReadOnly();
string domainAndUsername = @"192.168.1.113\[machine-name]\[username]";
string remoteMachineName = "*****";
PSCredential remoteCredential = new PSCredential(domainAndUsername, securePW);
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(false, remoteMachineName, 5985, "/wsman", shellUri, remoteCredential);
 using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
 {
   runspace.Open(); //__Error Here__//
```

> **PSRemotingTransportException**
>
> Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message:
>   Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

I can't find anything on the net. Even tell me am I correctly configuring the `connectionInfo` the IP, username and PC name etc.?

Comment: Are you running this as an administrator?

Comment: Umm u mean running VS as administrator?

Comment: For one thing, the triplet `ip_address\hostname\username` is not a valid username. Use either `hostname\username` for a local user or `domain\username` for a domain user. Also, does `username` have admin rights on the remote host? And did you actually check the [`about_Remote_Troubleshooting`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847850.aspx) help page?